# Close all browser instance in one go

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to close all browser instance opened by a test case in one go that is immediately when the test fails. I have opened more than one instance of same kind that is i am trying to automate chat application so i need to open two instance of same browser kind. But once the test fails, both the instance needs to be closed, but my test closes the browser for whom a particular step is failed. how to close both the browser instance when test fails for instance alone. `driver.quit()` is not working. As I have opened browser instance with different driver names i.e.

```
brow1.get(url)
```

and

```
brow2.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about calling `quit()` for both of them

```
brow1.quit();
brow2.quit();
```

Or for more generic way keep them in list and iterate over it.

```
browsers = []
browsers.append(brow1)
browsers.append(brow2)

for browser in browsers:
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: actually i am running all test cases together needed to call quit in teardown. so wrote quit funstion separately which goes and closes each browser with a try catch. and its working fine